# Changing the first payout address when a reward + fees is generated

Tags: bitcoind, solo-mining, mining-software, coinbase-transaction, mining-technical-details

I would like all my mined coins (solo mining, testnet so far) to go to a different default account.  I'm **not** referring to the distribution a mining pool will do to all of its miners (Pay per share, etc). Instead I'm talking about the first payout where a reward + fees is generated.

How would I go about doing this?

My goal is to make keep the private key (where the first 25 BTC is sent) offline and

Comment: What are you using to mine? I believe most pools have an address that you must set in your user account settings.

Comment: @ColinDean I want to create my own pool, and wherever the Bitcoind software creates the new block, it adds a 25 BTC coin output to the chain.  I want to edit and customize this specific address.  I may have to alter the source code

Comment: Unless you're hellbent on writing your own pool software, I recommend contributing to the development of one of the open source pool softwares. See [How can I start my own mining pool?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/446/how-can-i-start-my-own-mining-pool) for more information.

Comment: @Closers who said "Too Localised" - You probably misunderstood my question.  I clarified the question

Comment: This question ends in the middle of a sentence.